# Make NonlinearModelFit return continuous function

Tags: fitting

Suppose I want to fit the dataset

```
data={{10, 0.0251456}, {11, 0.0251456}, {12, 0.0251456}, {13,  0.0251456}, {14, 0.0251456}, {15, 0.0251456}, {16, 0.0251456}, {17,   29.4665}, {18, 54.5781}, {19, 67.7751}, {20, 76.1833}, {21,   82.0616}, {22, 86.4441}, {23, 89.8559}, {24, 92.6053}, {25,   94.879}, {26, 96.7872}, {27, 98.3832}, {28, 99.712}, {29,   100.8}, {30, 101.682}, {31, 102.401}, {32, 103.}, {33,   103.515}, {34, 103.997}, {35, 104.489}, {36, 105.031}, {37,   105.663}, {38, 106.418}, {39, 107.314}, {40, 108.345}}
```

to a piecewise model like this

```
fitModTot[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{
             {const, 10 <= x < 16}, 
             {a1*Erf[b1*(x - 15.99999)^c1], 16 <= x <= 27}, 
             {a0 + b0*x, x > 27}
            }
  ];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
         data, 
         fitModTot[x], 
         {const, {a1, 90}, {b1, 0.3}, {c1, 0.6}, {a0, 80}, {b0, 0.6}},
         x
      ];
```

What annoys me is the discontinuity at `x=27`. Is there a way to enforce `NonlinearModelFit` to make `fitModTot` a continous function or do I have to add in small $\varepsilon$ intervals with e.g. a polynomial defined on them to smoothely connect the three regimes as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547312)?

This is the output of `Plot[fit[x],{x,10,40}]`:
[image: Discontinuous piecewise function]

**Remark** It is not mandatory that there must be an `Erf[x]` dependence for $x\in[16,27]$. However, I would a) expect it (or something very similar) from underlying dynamics and b) prefer it over a polynomial fit since there should be a more "compact" form. However, a polynomial fit helps avoiding the discontinuity... So I suspect that it is just because an error function is not the best choice here?

**2nd remark** Basically I'd like to accept the answers by @MarcoB and @SjoerdC.deVries. However, after having written the answer to MarcoB's answer I concluded to accept his one since the exponential fit also makes sense. But again, it was more a 50:50 decision which one to accept - both solve the issue nicely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few considerations:

- Are you sure that you want `Erf` there and not just `Exp`? Your argument to `Erf` in the `Piecewise` function seems to suggest that you are trying to set up an "exponential rise to max" model. Your data seems to be better fit when `Exp` is swapped in for `Erf`, using your same arguments.
- I guess that the 15.99999 value in your `Piecewise` definition was there to avoid numerical instability. You can fix that by including 16 in the constant domain instead, i.e. `{const, 10 <= x <= 16}`.

---

Even better would be to start the linear part of your `Piecewise` function a little later in the data set:

```
Clear[fitModTot, fit]
fitModTot[x_] := Piecewise[{
    {const, 10 <= x <= 16},
    {a1*Exp[b1*(x - 16)^c1], 16 < x <= 29},
    {a0 + b0*x, x > 29}
    }];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
   data, fitModTot[x],
   {const, {a1, 90}, {b1, 0.3}, {c1, 0.6}, {a0, 80}, {b0, 0.6}}, x
   ];
Plot[fit[x], {x, 10, 40}, Epilog -> Point@data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `Exp` also works, I will consider it since it might also be a fit function that could probably deduced from the model. Also you're correct about the `15.999`: it was due to an error arising from the gradient at `x=16`. Simpliy including `x=16`into the constant part did not come to my mind... Thanks for this suggestion!

Comment: @Lukas Glad I could help! Thank you for the accept as well.

Answer (score 9):

Simple, just change your model so that continuity is guaranteed:

```
fitModTot[x_] := 
  Piecewise[
    {{const, 10 <= x < 16}, 
     {a1*Erf[b1*(x - 15.99999)^c1], 16 <= x <= 27}, 
     {a1*Erf[b1*(27 - 15.99999)^c1] + b0 (x - 27), x > 27}
     }]
```

`a0` isn't necessary anymore:

```
fit = 
NonlinearModelFit[
   data, 
   fitModTot[x], 
   {const, {a1, 90}, {b1, 0.3}, {c1, 0.6}, {a0, 80}, {b0, 0.6}}, 
   x];


Show[
 Plot[fit[x], {x, 10, 40}],
 ListPlot[data]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, that is probably the simplest solution. No idea why I didn't see it... Anyways, thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to force the piecewise function to be continuous at the breakpoints, then you must enforce that in your model.  This takes away one parameter from your model, namely the `a0` parameter

```
Solve[a1*Erf[b1*(x - 15.99999)^c1] == a0 + b0*x /. x -> 27, a0]

(*  {{a0 -> -1. (27. b0 - 1. a1 Erf[11.^c1 b1])}}   *)
```

Plug this back in,

```
fitModTot[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{const, 10 <= x < 16}, {a1*Erf[b1*(x - 15.99999)^c1], 
16 <= x <= 27}, {-1.` (27.` b0 - 1.` a1 Erf[11.00001`^c1 b1]) + 
  b0*x, x > 27}}];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  fitModTot[x], {const, {a1, 90}, {b1, 0.3}, {c1, 0.6}, {a0, 80}, {b0, 0.6}}, 
  x];
Plot[fit[x], {x, 10, 40}]
Show[Plot[fit[x], {x, 10, 40}], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Also many thanks to you for your answer.